# Accessing the contents of a list of objects that contain a list

Tags: c++, stl

I’ve been trying to get this working for a couple of weeks now. And I’m embarrassed. And I feel as if the answer is probably ridiculously simple.

I want to define a type of object (i.e. class) that contains a list, e.g. class ListA{string category; list< string > ingredients;…}. And then I want to create a list of those objects, e.g. list< ListA > myMenu. As you have already guessed, I can’t get it to work.

Here’s the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class ListA {
public:
    string category;
    list<string> items;

    ListA() { category = "Unentitled"; }
    ListA(const ListA& orig){}
    ~ListA(){}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout<<"\n\nTEST a6.3: Let's try an example that is more complete. ";

    //setup lists for each entree
    ListA ingredientsA;
    ingredientsA.category="Pizza";
    ingredientsA.items.push_back("tomatos"); ingredientsA.items.push_back("garlic");
    ingredientsA.items.push_back("cheese"); ingredientsA.items.push_back("dough");
    ListA ingredientsB;
    ingredientsB.category="Milk shake";
    ingredientsB.items.push_back("milk"); ingredientsB.items.push_back("ice cream");
    ingredientsB.items.push_back("cocoa"); ingredientsB.items.push_back("whip cream");

    //verify contents of lists are correctly added
    cout<<"\nTEST a.6.3.2[Category("<<ingredientsB.category<<")]";
    cout<<"\nTEST a.6.3.4[Ingredient("<<ingredientsB.items.front()<<")]";

    //add to our list of entries
    list< ListA > dishes;
    dishes.push_back(ingredientsA);
    dishes.push_back(ingredientsB);

    //grab first entree in dishes list just added, what the heck?
    ListA tmpa = dishes.front();
    cout<<"\nTEST a.6.3.5[Category("<<tmpa.category<<")]";
    cout<<"\nTEST a.6.3.6[Ingred size("<<tmpa.items.size()<<")]\n";

    //same with iterator
    list< ListA >::iterator itra = dishes.begin();
    cout<<"\nTEST a.6.3.5[Category("<<itra->category<<")]";
    cout<<"\nTEST a.6.3.6[Ingred size("<<itra->items.size()<<")]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
TEST a6.3: Let's try an example that is more complete. 
TEST a.6.3.2[Category(Milk shake)]
TEST a.6.3.4[Ingredient(milk)]
TEST a.6.3.5[Category()]
TEST a.6.3.6[Ingred size(0)]

TEST a.6.3.5[Category()]
TEST a.6.3.6[Ingred size(0)]

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

I create the list< ListA >, add ListA objects to it, and them immediately try to access the elements of that list and can't access a dang thing. (See a.6.3.5 & .6; the first is a direct access, the 2nd is with an iterator.)

Suggestions? What absolutely silly thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: Moral of the story -- don't code empty copy constructor, assignment operators, etc.,just as stubs or "I will fill this in later" type stuff. Either code the whole thing correctly, or make them private and unimplemented, or not write them at all. The compiler will be calling these stubbed out functions with the expectation that you will make copies correctly.

Comment: Well, I did say it was going to be embarrassing. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListA(const ListA& orig){}
```

Your class has an explicitly-declared copy constructor that does not copy anything.

When you declare a copy constructor, you become responsible for constructing the new object, completely, based on the contents of the object being copied.

Your constructor doesn't do anything. You end up constructing an empty object.

```
dishes.push_back(ingredientsA);
```

So, you create a list. And you copy `ingredientsA` to the end of the list, via `push_back()`.

Since your copy constructor does not really copy anything, you end up copying a completely empty class instance, into the `dishes` list.

Just get rid of your explicit copy constructor. It has no apparent purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
//add to our list of entries
list< ListA > dishes;
dishes.push_back(ingredientsA);
dishes.push_back(ingredientsB);
```

uses copy constructor to put *List* into *std::list* and your copy constructor overrides the default one and does nothing